# Why lone line in fortran code in one part is highlighted and become like comment?

Tags: fortran, visual-studio-2019, intel-fortran, freeform

I'm trying to write a fortran code for 1 phase flow in porous media.
In discretized equations and other long line I have a below problem as you see in the picture.
After that highlighted phrase my code become like comment.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome, please take the tour ans read [ask]. You cannot upload photographs of your monitor. Copy and paste all the important information **as text** directly into your question. Use the [edit] for that.

Comment: Looks like the IDE sees the code as fixed formatted code, but please follow the advise from Vladimir F

Comment: My bet would be that your lines are too long (above 72 in fixed form).

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://github.com/krvajal/vscode-fortran-support/issues/87):

> In its current state, the syntax highlighting for fixed-form Fortran in the extension only supports a line length of 72 characters. Anything after column 72 appears as comments (green) in the source code, which also affects the appearance of the following lines (when a closing parenthesis is in this green region for example)

You can change it on `fortran_fixed-form.tmLanguage.json` file or on the VS code settings.

Comment: You link a resource for Visual Studio Code while the question is tagged Visual Studio 2019. I recommend not answering so unclear and incomplete questions.